# Linux 14.04 upgrade errors

Tags: linux, ubuntu, updates, node.js

Whenever I run an update on my ubuntu 14.04 I get the following warnings:

```
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'node-normalize-package-data' missing ; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'node-sha' missing; assuming package  has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'node-which' missing; assuming packag e has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'node-slide' missing; assuming packag e has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'node-graceful-fs' missing; assuming  package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'node-ini' missing; assuming package  has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'node-mute-stream' missing; assuming  package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'node-lockfile' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'node-tunnel-agent' missing; assuming  package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'node-tar' missing; assuming package  has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'node-json-stringify-safe' missing; a ssuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'node-delayed-stream' missing; assumi ng package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'node-sigmund' missing; assuming pack age has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'node-once' missing; assuming packag$  has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'node-nopt' missing; assuming packag$  has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'node-cookie-jar' missing; assuming $ ackage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'node-read-package-json' missing; as$ uming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'node-async' missing; assuming packa$ e has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'node-inherits' missing; assuming pa$ kage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'node-minimatch' missing; assuming p$ ckage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'node-glob' missing; assuming packag$  has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'node-archy' missing; assuming packa$ e has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'node-osenv' missing; assuming packa$ e has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'node-mkdirp' missing; assuming pack$ ge has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'node-node-uuid' missing; assuming p$ ckage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'node-lru-cache' missing; assuming p$ ckage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'node-request' missing; assuming pac$ age has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'node-fstream' missing; assuming pac$ age has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'node-ansi' missing; assuming packag$  has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'node-retry' missing; assuming packa$ e has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'node-forever-agent' missing; assumi$ g package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'node-github-url-from-git' missing; $ ssuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'node-npmlog' missing; assuming packa ge has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'node-block-stream' missing, assuming  package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'node-abbrev' missing; assuming packa ge has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'node-mime' missing; assuming package  has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'node-read' missing; assuming package  has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'node-form-data' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'node-combined-stream' missing; assum ing package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'node-gyp' missing; assuming package  has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'node-qs' missing; assuming package h as no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'node-semver' missing; assuming packa ge has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'node-rimraf' missing; assuming packa ge has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'node-fstream-ignore' missing; assumi ng package has no files currently installed
```

Note: node programs are working fine on the machine. I dont understand, why these warnings?

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://serverfault.com/q/430682/286363) looks similar to yours, the solution he found was running this as root:

```
for package in $(apt-get upgrade 2>&1 | grep "warning: files list file for package '" | grep -Po "[^'\n ]+'" | grep -Po "[^']+"); do apt-get install --reinstall "$package"; done
```

Comment: I've tried it, doesn't help!